# Problems sending emails in post save signal in Django

Tags: django, django-signals, django-email

I'm trying to send a email after save some model in a `post_save` signal but when I save the model by first time the email is not sent, if I save the model a second time the email is sent.

#### Notes

The model has a `ManyToMany` field so I can't use `pre_save` signal because it throws a error: `<mymodel: mymodel_name object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

### What I have

#### Model

```py
class Message(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    """Representation of a Message."""

    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_("Recipients")
    )
    subject = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Subject"),
        help_text=_(
            "150 numbers / letters or fewer. Only letters and numbers are allowed."
        ),
        max_length=150,
        validators=[alphabets_accents_and_numbers],
    )
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Message"))
```

#### Signal

```py
@receiver(signal=post_save, sender=Message)
def send_message(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Send a email or Whatsapp if a new message is created."""
    recipient_emails = [recipient.email for recipient in instance.recipients.all()]
    attachments = []
    if instance.messagefile_set:
        for message_file in instance.messagefile_set.all():
            attachments.append((message_file.file.name, message_file.file.read()))
    send_mails(
        subject=instance.subject,
        message=instance.content,
        recipient_list=recipient_emails,
        attachments=attachments,
    )
```

#### Send mail wrapper to send emails

This is the function used in the signal to send emails.

```py
def send_mails(
    subject: str,
    message: str,
    recipient_list: List[str],
    from_email: Optional[str] = None,
    **kwargs,
) -> int:
    """Wrapper around Django's EmailMessage done in send_mail().
    Custom from_email handling and special Auto-Submitted header.
    """
    if not from_email:
        if hasattr(settings, "DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL"):
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
        else:
            from_email = "webmaster@localhost"
    connection = kwargs.get("connection", False) or get_connection(
        username=kwargs.get("auth_user", None),
        password=kwargs.get("auth_password", None),
        fail_silently=kwargs.get("fail_silently", None),
    )
    multi_alt_kwargs = {
        "connection": connection,
        "headers": {"Auto-Submitted": "auto-generated"},
    }
    mail = EmailMessage(
        subject=subject,
        body=message,
        from_email=from_email,
        to=recipient_list,
        **multi_alt_kwargs,
    )
    attachments = kwargs.get("attachments", None)
    if attachments:
        for attachment in attachments:
            if isinstance(attachment, MIMEBase):
                mail.attach(attachment)
            else:
                mail.attach(*attachment)
    return mail.send()
```

Comment: When you create an object, there are no objects in it m2m-relation. Only *after* the object is saved to the database, the m2m relation can be populationed, since it needs the pks of the objects it links, hence `instance.messagefile_set` is empty.

Comment: I would advice not to use signals, but simply call the function in the view(s) where you create `Message`s. Views serve a purpose, but often it is overused, and tends to be an antipattern https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have some questions; `instance.messagefile_set` only checks if the model has attachments, if it does it adds them to atachments, It doesn't control anything of the sending of messages. But considering what you wrote, the problem would be with the `recipients` field of the `Message` model. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: but the `recipients` is the same problem. All the m2m fields, and reversed `ForeignKey`s will be empty when the `post_save` function is triggered after *creating* the object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What happens if the process of sending the message is done from the admin, every time a user creates an object in the admin, there is no associated view.

Comment: @CristianCamiloForez: there is, in fact you can simply patch these in the `ModelAdmin`. See `save_model`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: It causes the same problem, but you gave me an address to follow with the empty fields of the type many to many, since the email will not yet have any recipient to send the message to the first time I save the model, is there any solution to solve this?, pre-populate the `manytomany` model so you can have recipients when you save the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you create the `Message`, and immediately after you *create* (not update) the `Message` (so when the `post_save` signal is called), all `ManyToManyField`s are empty, as well as the reverse of all `ForeignKey`s). This makes sense since *before* you can create a many-to-many relation between two records, these records need to be saved to the database, otherwise these records do not have a primary key, and thus these can not be linked.

I would advise not to use signals for this. Strictly speaking, you could try to work with an [**`m2m_changed`** signal [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed), like:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

def recipient_added(sender, instance, action, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        recipient_emails = list(get_user_model().objects.filter(pk__in=pk_set))
    

'm2m_changed'.connect(recipient_added, sender=Message.recipients.through)
```

But nevertheless, now it is possible that the `messagefile_set` is saved later, and we thus still have a problem.

I would advise to encapsulate the logic of sending emails in a function, and then call that function in the view *after* the object was created.

So if you for example have a view with a `MessageForm`:

```py
def send_message(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.save()
            send_messages(message)
```

Here the `form` will not only save the object, but also the many-to-many fields it handles. So after `form.save()` then saving of the object is *completely* finished.

In the `ModelAdmin` you can make use of the [**`save_related`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related):

```py
from django.contrib import admin

class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        send_mail(form.instance)
```

You can of course alter it. It is important to *first* call the `.save_related()` super method, since that will call the `form.save()` that will again handle the many-to-many relation, etc.

Comment: With this approach i'm having some problems when i attach files to the mail. When I attach heavy files, django send the mail but doesnt save the admin object in the DB. Rise `SMTPServerDisconnected at my_url Connection unexpectedly closed: The read operation timed out`.

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez: for large operations, you can not make use of the view. In that case you need an asynchronous queueing mechanism like rabbit-mq and celery for example https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html